# The smallest (and biggest) distance of points from the function

Tags: distance

please give me an advice.

I have points ("data", x and y coordinates). For these points, I created a residual function

`function = LinearModelFit [dat, x, x]`

Now I have to determine the point that has the smallest and largest distance from this line. And also a point that lies on a straight line. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it. I only know how to calculate the smallest / largest distance `(Min [function ["FitResiduals"]])` or `Max [function ["FitResiduals"]]`. But I would now need to see the given point with the corresponding coordinates (eg [0.2, 5])

Thank you for your answer

Comment: You can use `Ordering[function["FitResiduals"], 1]` to find the position of the smallest residual and then use that position to find the corresponding point in `dat`. You can use `Ordering[..., -1]` to find the position of the largest residual in the same manner.

Comment: [`MinimalBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinimalBy.html) and [`MaximalBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy.html) would work.